# Passing getCurrentAuditor Object response to a transient JPA field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, audit, transient

I am new to Spring Data's Auditor and facing with a peculiar scenario while trying to override the `getCurrentAuditor()`.

The auditor method returns an object of type `AuditData` (unlike String in most cases) and needs to be consumed by a transient field annotated with @CreatedBy in `AuditPO` class.

```
@CompileStatic
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
class AuditData {
    UUID userId
    UUID profileId
}
```

`AuditPO` class contains various columns related to persisting audit info. This class is extended by each entity, so that the corresponding entity table has the same set of columns with appropriate audit info.

A sample is provided below with Role & Permission tables. `RolePO`/`PermissionPO` extends `UuidPO` which eventually extends this `AuditPO`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'Role')
@ToString(includeNames = true, includeSuper = true) 
class RolePO extends UuidPO {

    @NotNull(message = '{role.name.required}')
    @Size(max = 30, message = '{role.name.size}')
    String name

    @Size(max = 100, message = '{role.description.size}')
    String description
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'Permission')
@ToString(includeNames = true, includeSuper = true)
class PermissionPO extends UuidPO {

    @NotNull(message = '{permission.name.required}')
    @Size(max = 36, message = '{permission.name.size}')
    String name

    @Size(max = 100, message = '{permission.description.size}')
    String description
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
@ToString(includeNames = true)
abstract class UuidPO extends AuditPO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = 'uuid2')
    @GenericGenerator(name = 'uuid2', strategy = 'uuid2')
    @Column(columnDefinition = 'VARCHAR(36)')
    @Type(type = 'uuid-char')
    UUID id
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener)
@ToString(includeNames = true)
abstract class AuditPO {

    @CreatedBy
    AuditData create

    @LastModifiedBy
    AuditData update

    @Type(type = 'uuid-char')
    UUID createdByProfileId

    @Type(type = 'uuid-char')
    UUID updatedByProfileId

    @Type(type = 'uuid-char')
    UUID createdByUserId

    @Type(type = 'uuid-char')
    UUID updatedByUserId

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3)")
    Date createDate

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3)")
    Date updateDate
}
```

The end goal is to map the `auditData.userId` to `auditPO.(created/updated)ByUserId`  and `auditData.profileId` to `auditPO.(created/updated)ByProfileId`.

One approach that I was exploring was to create something like below:

```
@Transient 
@CreatedBy
AuditData create
```

and then use the `@PrePersist` option of JPA to act on the values obtained, so that I could map to the respective fields as I need. However, I wasn't very successful there. The other option I explored was around creating a different EntityListener class and using that in the AuditPO, but wasn't very fruitful either (Maybe am missing something in the latter approach).

Also, a lot of samples dealing with handling object type return from `getCurrentAuditor()` had the AuditPO class with an instance variable for @CreatedBy/@UpdatedBy which would then have JOIN with another table. Our model doesn't go with that approach. Each entity table needs those two columns.

I would really appreciate any help in achieving the goal listed above.

P.S.: Data storage - MySQL 5.7.23, ORM - Hibernate, Spring - 4.2.x

Comment: Your question is rather broad/vague. You just write:  "I wasn't very successful there". What did you expect to happen? and what did actually happen?


In any case: why do you want to make the field transient? The whole point of this auditing bussiness is normally to persist that information to the database.

Comment: Hi @JensSchauder! Thanks for taking your time to respond. So expectation is to map the getCurrentAuditor values to different columns in my AuditorPO. I could not achieve that as the response gets mapped to only non transient fields annotated with @CreatedBy/@LastModifiedBy & I cannot afford to have such fields like 
```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn 
@JoinColumn
private AuditData createdBy;
```
 which requires a separate table for persisting audit data. We want the fields 
 in AuditData mapped to respective columns in each table. Sorry if I wasn't verbose, let me know.

Comment: So what is the purpose of all this, if you can't afford to store it in the database? Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: Ah! sorry. So the purpose is to store it, but not in the format mentioned above i.e. `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn private AuditData createdBy`. So if I have an entity table called Role, am going to have 2 columns in the same table say createdByProfileId & createdByUserId whose values are going to be returned from the getCurrentAuditor of type AuditData. I wanted to approach it by having a transient field which did the `@Transient @CreatedBy AuditData create` & use the JPA @PrePersist method to get the AuditData response from this transient field & map it to the 2 corresponding UUID fields/columns.

Comment: Could you make the audit information an `@Embeddable`?

Comment: Hi @JensSchauder! I did try `@Embeddable` earlier, but with lesser focus on that. After your suggestion, did manage to dive deeper and figure out a solution. Also, I guess the spring-data-commons version mattered when I went with the approach of `@Embeddable` (worked with versions 2.1.0 and above)! Thanks a lot for your support and the perfect suggestion. I'll post a detailed solution which may help others as well.